# FluxProcessor: retrieve last emitted value on subscribe like rx's Subject

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Currently, `FluxProcessor` subscription retrieve only those values that being emitted after subscription. But I want to retrieve last value in Flux on the moment of subscription, for example, like RX's `Subject` do.

I have this setup:

```java
FluxProcessor<Integer, Integer> processor = DirectProcessor.<Integer>create().serialize();
FluxSink<Integer> sink = processor.sink();

sink.next(1);

stateProcessor.subscribe(System.out:println);

sink.next(2);
```

Output is:

```
1
```

Desired output:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it using `ReplayProcessor`. It is able to store N last emitted values for further subscriptions. For the same example:

```java
FluxProcessor<Integer, Integer> processor = ReplayProcessor.<Integer>create(1).serialize(); //1 is the history size
FluxSink<Integer> sink = processor.sink();

sink.next(1);

stateProcessor.subscribe(System.out:println);

sink.next(2);
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```